# How can I create an ERD for my phpmyadmin database?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, erd

Is there a way I can create an Entity Relationship Diagram for my PHPMyAdmin database?

Comment: Could be available in [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) …

Comment: ERD?  That's an emergency recovery Disk for an OS recovery so I don't see the tie in.  Perhaps you should elaborate.

Comment: @uSlackr - Entity Relationship Diagram - there is a major shortage of unique three letter acronyms.  (or were you kidding?)

Comment: LOL!I'm an idiot

Answer (score 2):

AFAK it can't be done using PHPMyAdmin but take a look on MySQL workbench it's a great tool to do this and you can connect to your local/remote database server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create ERD with PHPMyAdmin from version 3.4 or greater. You can refer to PHPMyAdmin documentation for more info: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#pmadb

detail step to generate ERD : http://goo.gl/0z3vFE